# Thread-safety vs atomicity in C

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, thread-safety

As far as I know, thread-safe functions can be called without needing to mutex or semaphore. Can't they?

For example, `strcpy()` or `strdup()` is kinda thread safe function.

But when I was reading the man-page, I saw the following and don't understand the saying along with the bolded example.

> Being MT-Safe does not imply a function is atomic, nor that it
>                 uses any of the memory synchronization mechanisms POSIX
>                 exposes to users.  It is even possible that calling MT-Safe
>                 functions in sequence does not yield an MT-Safe combination.
>                 **For example, having a thread call two MT-Safe functions one
>                 right after the other does not guarantee behavior equivalent
>                 to atomic execution of a combination of both functions, since
>                 concurrent calls in other threads may interfere in a
>                 destructive way.**

Is the following usage wrong in a thread's function? If yes, what are the wrong points? If no, what is the meaning of quoted saying with the bolded one?

```
char *s1 = calloc(14, 1);
char *s2 = calloc(6, 1);
char *s3 = strdup("soner");
char *s4 = strdup("stackoverflow");
strcpy(s2, s3);
strcpy(s1, s4);
s1[13] = s2[5] = 0;

mutex_lock(&mtx);
printf("%s %s", s1, s2);
fflush(stdout);
mutex_unlock(&mtx);

free(s1);
free(s2);
free(s3);
free(s4);
```

Comment: All it is saying is that using thread-safe functions to implement _your_ algorithm does not make your algorithm thread-safe.

Comment: Re, "strcpy()...is kinda thread safe." No. `strcpy()` and `strdup()` are not thread _safe_, they are thread _agnostic_. The only memory locations accessed by those functions are their own local variables, and locations to which your program provides pointers. If your threads don't provide pointers to _shared_ buffers, when calling `strcpy()` or `strdup()` then there will be no need for thread-safety because there's no possibility of collision. If, on the other hand, your threads _do_ provide pointers to shared data, then it's _your_ responsibility to ensure the safety.

Comment: I'd love to hear the definition for "kinda thread safe", is it the same as "kinda pregnant"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"MT-Safe" in this context only means that you can call the function from multiple threads, not that there's any synchronization between the threads.

For example, you have two threads where one is doing `strcpy(s1, "foo")` and the other is doing `strcpy(s1, "bar")` (and `s1` is a buffer shared between the threads), then you have a data-race as both threads could attempt to write to the destination `s1` simultaneously.

Comment: ... or if one thread does `char s1[] = "foo"; strcpy(s1,"bar")` and the other thread does `strcpy(s2,s1)` with no synchronization it is not guaranteed that `s2` will get the value `"foo"` or `"bar"`, it might also get a partially changed value, e.g. `"boo"`.

Comment: if s1 is an array or a pointer to char, isn't it per-thread?  since it is defined in a thread's function, it is in thread's stack. ??

Comment: @Bodo I don't think it is possible. The fact that s1[]="foo" is in thread's stack space does mean it is special to the thread. When the other thread comes, it does same thing. Is it wrong?

Comment: @Som.prog.du. if the buffer is shared, of course race is apparent.

Comment: @Bodo it is possible only and only if s2 is shared source.

Comment: @snr Well yes if all of the data is local to the thread (which isn't clearly spelled out in the question IMO) then there's no problem what so ever. And that what's "MT-safe" means. Maybe a better term would be "thread reentrant"?

Comment: @some reentrancy has a very specific meaning that doesn't fit here imo. The concept here is very simple and really just means that any static data the function may use is correctly synchronized. The classic counter example is rand() which isn't safe to call in parallel.

Comment: Could someone give a example of function that is not a MT-function without incurring data-race problems? Why a "standard" function could not be called safely in C?